# WebAPI OData failed validation ModelState object not returned

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, validation, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an AngularJS web form to perform a POST (insert) into a table using WebAPI setup as OData.  I am trying to get back a failed validation ModelState object back (in JSON format) to validate the appropriate fields on a form.

All I get back is a single string with all the details in as a string (not in a JSON parsable format)

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"The request is invalid."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"application.ApplicationName : The ApplicationName field is required.\r\n","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

My post method looks like this:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Application application)
        {
           if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Applications.Add(application);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Created(application);
        }
```

I have even tried abstracting this to a ActionFilterAttribute, but still the same result

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {

                var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

                if (!modelState.IsValid)
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                         .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);

            }
        }
    }
```

My WebApi start method has the following configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Application>("DataApplications");
            config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());


            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include };

            Configure(config);

            config.EnableQuerySupport();

            // Use camel case for JSON data.
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

This is what I want to achieve (not matched to my example above):

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": { 
        "car": [
            "Required property 'Make' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 57."
        ],
        "car.Make" : [
            "The Make field is required."
        ], 
        "car.Price": [
            "The field Price must be between 0 and 200000."
        ]
    }
}
```

I need the ModelState back so I can target validation feedback at the appropriate fields.

Any ideas what I can check / change to get this to work as desired?

Thanks.

**Update 1 - reference found on asp.net**

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/aspnet-and-web-tools-20122-release-notes

OData error response does not contain model state errors

When creating an error response using the CreateErrorResponse extension methods or HttpErrors directly the error is mapped to an OData error response. Any model state errors in the error response do not get propagated to the OData error response. To preserve the model state errors in the OData error response use the CreateODataErrorResponse extension method or ODataError directly and add descriptions of the model state errors to the OData error message.

Comment: Can you please share the solution if you have found it?

Answer (score 0):

OData uses `ODataError` as a error response. The difference between `ODataError` and `HttpEror` is that HttpError derive from `Dictionary<string, object>` so when it's instatiated with `ModelStateDictionary`, all model errors are set to `ModelState` property. But, when you're requesting OData, `HttpError` object is mapped to `ODataError` and all validation errors are concatenated into `InnterError` property.